# Display PHP output in Ajax Popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, magnific-popup

*Hi All! So I'm a noob, and most of my code was done by a programmer for me. I can't get him to help me now.*

I have a calculator that displays results (produced by calc.php) without relaoding the page. **Demo is here: http://www.roofingcalculator.org/popup/popup.htm**

Now I added Ajax popup (contact form) from here: http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ and it works.

What I want is to display the results of calc.php inside the Popop, but it does not work.

Details:

When user clicks "Calculate" button, the form sends info to CALC.JS using POST, which then sends info to CALC.PHP and diplays results back on the page with this tag:

```
<span id="CalcSum">Results:</span>
```

When I add the SPAN tag to popup, it does not display the result of PHP.

**QUESTION**  How do I display results in AJAX Popup??

Please help - I really appreciate any help - Cheers!

**Calc.js content:**

```
var XmlHttp;
function GetXmlHttpObject() {
   var XmlHttp = null;
   try {
      XmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } catch (e) {
      try {
         XmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
         XmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
   }
   return XmlHttp;
}
function StateChanged() {
   if (XmlHttp.readyState == 4 || XmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
      document.getElementById("CalcSum").innerHTML = XmlHttp.responseText;
   }
}
function ShowSum(url, params) {
   XmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
   if (XmlHttp == null)
      return;
   XmlHttp.onreadystatechange = StateChanged; 
   XmlHttp.open('POST', url, true);
   XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
   XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   XmlHttp.send(params);
}

function GetInfo() {var str = 
"size1=" + escape(encodeURI(document.getElementById("size1").value)) +
"&size2=" + escape(encodeURI(document.getElementById("size2").value));

ShowSum('http://www.website.com/calc.php', str);
}
```

**calc.php**

```
<?php
$size1_val    = empty($_POST['size1'])      ? '0'       : $_POST['size1'];
$size2_val    = empty($_POST['size2'])      ? '0'       : $_POST['size2'];
$total_size = $size1_val * $size2_val;
print "Result: ". round($total_size). "";
?>
```

**HTML Form:**

```
<table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="calc.js"></script>
<form id="formcalc" action="javascript:GetInfo();" accept-charset="UNKNOWN" 
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">
<tr>
<td height="24" ><strong>Sizes:</strong>
</td>
<td height="24" valign="top" width="50%">
<input id="size2"/> x <input id="size1" s/> ft.
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td COLSPAN="2">
<input name="calc" type="submit" value="Calculate" />

<span id="CalcSum">Results:</span>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you try alert( XmlHttp.responseText) in function StateChanged and check response ok or not

Comment: Still not sure why you don't have all the calculations done in JS.  It'll be much faster and use a lot less resources on your web server.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't know JS ... What exactly should I change?

Comment: Verosion - The calculator is more sophisticated than that (I did not provide entire code, becuase it is irrelevant) and I don't want othrs to use the code - that's why I use JS + PHP ... I've had it stolen before  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `$('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup('open');` to your stateChanged function as below. Works for me on your example. Changed both results spans and opens the pop up.

```
function StateChanged() {
   if (XmlHttp.readyState == 4 || XmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
       $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup('open');
      document.getElementById("CalcSum").innerHTML = XmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("CalcSumPopup").innerHTML = XmlHttp.responseText;
   }
}
```

Update: more documentation here http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html if you need it.

Comment: Awesome - works perfectly! Thank you very much. I wish I also could help you with something! One side note - there seems to be a slight delay (0.5-1 second) before results / popup appear - Is it becaue of PHP or JS being slow? PS - i saw documentation, but I do not understand it :)

Comment: one more question: How can I make it so that popup shows only once per session? Say if user click "calculate" second time, only result on page is shown, but no popup second time?

Answer (score 1):

Is the html for the Ajax popup on the same page as the form? If so, add

```
<span id="CalcSumPopup">Results:</span>
```

to the popup where you want the result to go and add

```
document.getElementById("CalcSumPopup").innerHTML = XmlHttp.responseText;
```

after `document.getElementById("CalcSum").innerHTML = XmlHttp.responseText;` in Calc.js.

If it is not on the same page this will not work.

EDIT:
This works because id's are meant to be unique. getElementById will find the first occurrence of the specified id and then stop, so if you want multiple places to be changed you need to give them unique id's.

Comment: AWESOME!!! THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!! You are great! Follow up question: How do I display Result on BOTH page and in POPUP (in case user closes popup window)?

Comment: Follow up question: How do I display Result on BOTH page and in POPUP (in case user closes popup window)? Currently, the call for popup is the following: `<a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">popup</a>` 

How do I make "calculate" button Triger popup AND display results on page?

Comment: You want the calculate button to open the popup if it is closed?

Comment: no, I want the "calculate" button to do 2 things:

1) Open popup with **CalcSumPopup**
2) Show results on page (as it is right now) - dispaly **CalcSum**

The "triger" for popup is `class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form"` but if I add it to the Calculate button, `<input class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form" name="calc" type="submit" value="Calculate" />` results do not show on either PAGE or POPUP

Comment: I am not sure if i have enough information. Try adding window.location.href="#test-form"; to the calculate button trigger code or alternately before document.getElementById("CalcSum").innerHTML = XmlHttp.responseText; in Calc.js.

Comment: not working

If i add it to JS file, then CalcSumPopup does not display
If I add it to <input>, results display ON PAGE, without popup 

What information can I give you?

Comment: It's hard without being able to see how your popup is set up. Read [link](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#ajax_type) specifically "To modify content after it’s loaded, or to select and show just specific element from loaded file, there is a parseAjax callback:" I think it might be relevant. Maybe you need to load the content separately from doing the calculation.

Comment: I'm using "inline popup with form" setup from this page http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/ it is set up prettiy much the same way. I did download the big JS and CSS from their Build Tool, but the popup code is structured the same as expample on that page. Then I just modify the HTML of what is shown in popup and add calculator output in there.