# PHP Calculator - Show results on page and in Ajax Popup

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup, magnific-popup

UPDATE - this was solved by adding `$('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup('open');` to the StateChanged function in the JS. Thanks to @Bollis.

Original Question:

I have a simple calculator here: http://www.roofingcalculator.org/popup/popup.htm

when click on "Calculate" button, i need results to be displayed on that page AND initiate Ajax Popup ([Magnific](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) inline) with results displayed in popup as well.

**Question:** How do i make it so that pressing "calculate" button would both of these at the same time:

1) display results on page

2) Launch pupup with results of calculator

[image]

Right now, to show Popup, user needs to click on the link "Open Form".

If you open popup AND don't click "calculte" button, no results are displayed.

If you click Calculate first and then open popup, results are shown on both the page and in popup (see image).

The two things that initiate popup are:

```
<a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form">
```

If i add ***class="popup-with-form"*** and ***href="#test-form"*** to the Calculate button, it launches popup, but no calculation is done.

All codes for calculator (JS / PHP) can be seen [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25007571/display-php-output-in-ajax-popup).

**Here is AJAX code that opens popup (i think)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup({
        type: 'inline',
        preloader: false,
        focus: '#name',

        // When elemened is focused, some mobile browsers in some cases zoom in
        // It looks not nice, so we disable it:
        callbacks: {
            beforeOpen: function() {
                if($(window).width() < 700) {
                    this.st.focus = false;
                } else {
                    this.st.focus = '#name';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `onsubmit="openPopupFunctionHere()"` to your `form` tag. The `onsubmit` event will be triggered whenever the form should submit, which happens when you press the "Calculate" button.

Comment: Can you help me structure the `openPopupFunctionHere()` please. I do not know JS .. and the popup is Ajax, which is even more confusing. I've added AJAX code to the original question

Comment: The code for the popup seems to be jQuery, not Ajax. jQuery is a Javascript library. I'm afraid I do not really understand how the popup code works. Please refer to the Magnific Popup documentation for that, if possible; or maybe someone who is more familiar with jQuery than I am can help you out.

Comment: (sorry, I don't know the difference between JQuery and Ajax :) ... Basically I agree with you that I need some JS function that triggers openig the popup ... I just don't know how to do it :(

Comment: thanks for help. Bollis helped me solve this in the previous question by adding `$('.popup-with-form').magnificPopup('open');` to the StateChanged function in the JS file